# how do i unblock img-src "http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico blocked img-src"

Tags: css, pug

i  have a background image in css and am using pug template but in the console i get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) logIn:Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:3000'

```
body {
  
    background-image:url(../pictures/farmProducts.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

doctype html  
html(lang="en")
    head
        title UFarm
        <!-- link css files-->
        link(href='css/index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all')
    <!--main-->
    body
        .main-layouts.wrapper(style='padding: 60px;')
            h1 UFarm LogIn Form
            .main-inputs
                .spacing
                    form(action='/aoDashboard' method='post' name='form')
                        input.text(type='text' name='userName' placeholder='Username' required='')
                        input.text(type='password' name='passWord' placeholder='Password' required='')
                        input(type='submit' value='SIGNUP' onclick='access();')
                    p Don't have an account? 
                        a(href='signUp')  SignUp!
      script(src='../public/js/login.js')
```